# Is cofficient of restitution equation valid for collisions involving more than 2 bodies?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I couldn't solve a question and the only equation I was missing was of cofficient of restitution i.e. $e=\frac{v_{final2} - v_{final1}}{u_{intial1} - u_{initial2}}$ .
But the collision was among 3 objects. This was the figure given in the question: [image]
(elasticity given was 1, fwiw)

Won't the third body or the tension impact the velocities? Is coefficient of restitution equation generally valid when collision among 3 bodies takes place?
Like would the equation be applicable when masses are aligned this way:[image]

Edit: the aforementioned question

[image]

Edit 2: I have mentioned more on what exactly I am having doubt in the comment section of 147875 sir's answer.

Comment: It would be nice, if you provide the complete question/exercise.

Comment: @147875  Added that in the edit

Comment: At the instant of impact, all three spheres form a equilateral triangle. Try to find the components of momentum along the triangle sides and apply elastic collision rules.

Comment: Already did that. But didn't get at the correct answer. "Apply elastic collision rules"-for this I wrote the energy conservation equation. But in the solution they had used the equation mentioned in the question rather than the one I applied. I just have a doubt in that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **coefficient of restitution (e)** is always **between** bodies (i.e., two bodies) rather than **among** bodies (i.e., more than 2 bodies). If you want to deal more than two bodies, always take two at a time along with appropriate components.

The coefficient of restitution (e) is defined as,

$$
e = \frac{\text{Relative velocity after collision}}{\text{Relative velocity before collision}}
$$

If the initial velocity of the center sphere is $u$ and let $u'$ be the velocity after collision and $v$ be the velocity of suspended spheres, which are constrained to move in horizontal direction. Then, coefficient of restitution (e) is given by

$$
e = \frac{v\cos(60^\circ) - u'\cos(30^\circ)}{u\cos(30^\circ)} \tag{1}
$$

for elastic collision, $e = 1$, you can substitute in (1) and to get

$$
\sqrt{3}(u + u')  = v \tag{2}
$$

In deriving the result above, we took the center sphere along with one of the bottom spheres. We can equation (2) along with equation due to impulse to solve the problem.

**Edit 1:**

> Really thanks but I am still confused. What I really want to know is
> that- the external force and the extra body would impact the velocity
> just after impact of both the bodies but still the equation gives
> correct results. Why didn't the equation fail in this situation? What
> principle is it really based on? Like momentum conservation is not
> applicable here but the equation is still valid. I have phrased the
> question really badly

When solving the problem, we only took the primary collision and the consecutive collisions is not considered. Does the third body have any effect on the velocity of the other two? Yes it does, that's the reason, we took component only along one body and derived the result (1) and (2). Is momentum conservation applicable here? All the laws of elastic collision? Yes it does. We will derive this result below.

Conservation of Kinetic Energy gives,

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}mu^2 &= \frac{1}{2}m{u'}^2 + 2 \times \frac{1}{2}m'v^2 \\
\implies m(u^2 - {u'}^2) &= m'v^2 \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

conservation of momentum gives,
Alng $x$-axis is,

$$
0 = m'v\sin(30^\circ) - m'v\sin(30^\circ) \tag{4}
$$

Along $y$-axis is,

$$
\begin{align}
mu & = mu' + 2 \times m'v\cos(30^\circ) \\
\implies m(u - u') &= \sqrt{3}m'v \tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

Divide Eq(3) by Eq(5) gives,

$$
(u + u') = \frac{v}{\sqrt{3}} \tag{6}
$$

Now, if we look Eq(2) and Eq(6) are both same. Hence rules of elastic collision is applicable.

Comment: Really thanks but I am still confused. What I really want to know is that- the external force and the extra body would impact the velocity just after impact of both the bodies but still the equation gives correct results. Why didn't the equation fail in this situation? What principle is it really based on? Like momentum conservation is not applicable here but the equation is still valid. I have phrased the question really badly

Comment: Momentum is conserved. Please look at the new edit, I derived the result only using elastic collision rules.

Comment: I have some major lacunas in my understanding. Please, help me finding where I am going wrong. l I think there is impulse of tension in the y axis so we can't conserve momentum in y axis. We can conserve momentum in x axis but it won't give us any fruitful result. Also, I would have used the equation $0=mv-mv$ for x axis because v is already in the horizontal direction. Can you please tell me why you have used $vsin(30°)$ in equation 4?

Comment: Yes, the bottom spheres are suspended by a string is a constraint which prevents the spheres from moving further down. But for a moment we neglected it to derive the result. To be honest, the above problem is an inelastic collision because the transnational kinetic energy is not conserved, since linear motion turns into a rotational motion due to strings. We simplified it to solve this. When it comes to second question, I assumed $v$ along the direction of triangle side, so the respective component is $v\sin(30^\circ)$